# Multiple nested functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am kind of back engineering a javascript project and need to inject a function into some already writeen code.

I want to be able to call something like the following function in javascript:

human.mouth.shout(word);

So this would call the function that makes the object 'shout'.

My question is, how I create child attributes of the human object. As far as I know, I can only have one nested function in javascript, so at the most basic I have something like this:

```
function HumanObj(){
    this.shout = function(word){
        alert(word);
    }
}
```

Then to call this, I would use:

```
var human = new HumanObj;
human.shout("HELLO WORLD");
```

So this would give us our alert: "HELLO WORLD".

So how would I break this up so I could call it using the following?

```
var human = new HumanObj;
human.mouth.shout("HELLO WORLD");
```

Have tried this, but didn't work - assume you can't have too many levels of nested functions...

```
function HumanObj(){
    this.mouth = function(){
         this.shout = function(word){
            alert(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
function HumanObj(){
    this.mouth = {
        shout: function(word){
            alert(word);
        }
    };
}
```

Or if you need `mouth` to be *instantiatable* (with additional stuff in its prototype), you can do:

```
function HumanObj(){
    function mouthObj() {
        this.shout = function(word){
            alert(word);
        }
    }
    this.mouth = new mouthObj();
}
```

Comment: Top way worked great. Sorry I don't have quite enough rep to vote you up, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @web_la - Thats never an issue. Gald it helped. :-)

Comment: @web_la You can't vote up, but you can accept the answer by click on the little tick mark. That's worth much more than an upvote.